# How to loop through a DataTable SELECT query to get all the records with the same linked_comp_id

Tags: c#, loops

So I need to loop through the query and then generate a pdf report with all the records found between 2 dates that are linked to a company. My problem is that the query only selects the first record and the pdf then generates the same record for the amount of records that are linked to a company meaning if 4 records are found it the pdf generates 4 tables of the same record instead of 4 different records.

the query

```
public static DataTable db_reports( int comp_id, DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
        {
            DataTable Table = new DataTable();
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(helpers.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand Command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    Command.CommandText = @"SELECT id, linked_comp_id, comp_name, client_comp_name, inv_number, inv_date, due_date, ref_number, pastel_ref, status_id, 
                                            invoice_total FROM view_Invoices WHERE inv_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate";
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@linked_comp_id", comp_id);

                    using (MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command))
                    {

                        Adapter.Fill(Table);
                        return Table;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

the button that generates the pdf

```
            start_date = DateTime.TryParse(txt_start_date.Text, out start_date) ? start_date : DateTime.MinValue;
            end_date = DateTime.TryParse(txt_end_date.Text, out end_date) ? end_date : DateTime.MinValue;


            Session["invoice_name"] = "REPORT " + DateTime.Now;

            Response.Write("<script>window.open('view_report.aspx',target='new');</script>");
```

pdf code

```
DataTable dtR = db_Reports.db_reports(linked_id, startdate, enddate);

                foreach (DataRow r in dtR.Rows)
                {
                    if (dtR.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        table = new PdfPTable(7);
                        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 3f, 3f, 3f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f });

                        table.WidthPercentage = 93;

                        //row 1
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Invoice Number", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Invoice Date", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Due Date", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Client Refrence", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Pastel Reference", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Status", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total", titleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE; table.AddCell(cell);


                        //row 2
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(invR.inv_number, subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(invR.inv_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(invR.due_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(invR.ref_number, subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(invR.pastel_ref, subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(invR.status_id.ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(invR.invoice_total.ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);

                        doc.Add(table);



                doc.Add(new Paragraph(new Phrase(new Chunk(" ", titleFont))));
                doc.Add(new Paragraph(new Phrase(new Chunk(" ", titleFont))));

                    }
                }
```

And the pdf redirect page

```
int comp_id = int.TryParse(Session["comp_id"].ToString(), out comp_id) ? comp_id : 0;
                int logged_in_id = int.TryParse(Session["logged_in_id"].ToString(), out logged_in_id) ? logged_in_id : 0;

                int id = int.TryParse(Session["linked_comp_id"].ToString(), out id) ? id : 0;

                iTextSharp.text.Image comp_logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(".") + "/img/logo.jpg");
                DateTime date1 = reports.start_date;
                DateTime date2 = reports.end_date;
                string _name = reports.compName;
                MemoryStream memoryStream = itext_docs.pdf_report(id, comp_logo, date1, date2);

                Byte[] buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();

                if (buffer != null)
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Session["invoice_name"].ToString() + ".pdf");
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that i was using the `invR` in the foreach loop when i should have been using the `DataRow r`.

```
 foreach (DataRow r in dtR.Rows)
                {
                    if (dtR.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //row 2

                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r["inv_number"].ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r["inv_date"].ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r["due_date"].ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r["ref_number"].ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r["pastel_ref"].ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r["status_id"].ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(r["invoice_total"].ToString(), subTitleFont)); cell.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK; table.AddCell(cell);
                    }
                }
```